# Synonym for urban

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

If I am speaking about the built/man-made environment do I use the word urban or there is another/better word to use?

Comment: Why doesn't '*urban*' serve your purpose?

Comment: I am using "urban" in my text as an antonym of  "rural "  so I don't want a misconception to happen by using it again in a  different meaning

Comment: Did a thesaurus suggest anything?

Comment: yes, civil/civic/metropolitan

Comment: so I'm using the idiom "urban development" but not in the sense urbanizing the community rather in upgrading the condition of the built environment. I hope that explains my question.

Answer (score 1):

[Metropolitan](https://www.lexico.com/definition/metropolitan)?

As adjective:

1 Relating to or denoting a metropolis.
‘the Boston metropolitan area’

2 Relating to or denoting the parent state of a colony.
‘metropolitan Spain’

3 (Christian Church)
Relating to or denoting a metropolitan or his see.
‘a metropolitan bishop’

Granted, it implies a very large city (one worthy of being called metropolis) so it might not fit your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

man-made/man-built ... **artificial**

> **artificial**
>   ADJECTIVE
>   1. Made or produced by human beings rather than occurring naturally, especially as a copy of something natural.
>   ‘her skin glowed in the artificial light’
>   ‘an artificial limb’
>   ‘artificial flowers’

[Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/artificial)